# Count data in multiple Excel file vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple xls files in a folder.

In column G:G of help worksheet, it has datas like O , R

I want to count total number of O, R individually and put it in a excel table.

i have this code please help its not executing the loop also

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim CSVfolder As String, _
    Xlsfolder As String, _
    fname As String, _
    wbook As Workbook, _
    SRange As Range, _
    k As Integer

Xlsfolder = "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\macro\macro\macro"

fname = Dir(Xlsfolder & "*.xls")
k = 5
Do While fnmae <> ""
Workbooks.Open (fnamme)

Set SRange = Workbooks(fname).Worksheets("Findings").Range("G:G")
Cells(3, k) = Application.CountIf(SRange, "O")
Cells(4, k) = Application.CountIf(SRange, "Cd")
Cells(5, k) = Application.CountIf(SRange, "Cr")
Cells(6, k) = Application.CountIf(SRange, "Cn")
Cells(7, k) = Application.CountIf(SRange, "A")
Cells(8, k) = Application.CountIf(SRange, "Cf")

Workbooks(fname).Close

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please share with us what have you tried till now to resolve your problem?

Comment: I'm troll guessing, not much... So here is a basic to open files in a folder : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30758554/4628637 You'll just have to tune it to fit your need and if you're stuck come back here to ask a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something very simple, like this.

```
=('NAME_OF__SHEET'!A1)

NAME_OF__SHEET = "the name of your sheet" A1 = column, row

and your done!
```

Or, of course, you can use VBA to import your data from several files into one sheet, and work on it there.

```
Sub combine()

    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = False

    Dim wbM As Workbook
    Set wbM = Workbooks("main")

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True
    Files = fd.Show

    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        app.Workbooks.Open fd.SelectedItems(i)
    Next i

    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In app.Workbooks
        If wb.Name <> "main.xlsm" Then
            Dim wsN As Worksheet
            Set wsN = wbM.Sheets.Add(after:=wbM.Sheets(wbM.Sheets.Count))
            wsN.Name = wb.Name

            wbM.Sheets(wb.Name).Range("A1:K1").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:K1").Value

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Next

    app.Quit
    Set app = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thnak u it helped me a bit ty so much