# Can I call datas from CSV file to my VBA script?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I want to take some datas from another file in excel to come to my main file, I have no problem at all with this code:

```
Sub Call()
'
' Call Macro
'
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(('C:\Users\prosp\Documents\Kabu\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[1]C[-1])-('C:\Users\prosp\Documents\Kabu\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[1]C[-4])=0,""0"",('C:\Users\prosp\Documents\Kabu\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[1]C[-1])-('C:\Users\prosp\Documents\Kabu\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[1]C[-4]))"
    Range("F4").Select

End Sub
```

But if the file's type change to .csv file, I can't call the datas which I want to use. The code was like this:

```
Sub Call()
'
' Call Macro
'
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(('C:\Users\prosp\Documents\Kabu\[Book1.csv]Sheet1'!R[1]C[-1])-('C:\Users\prosp\Documents\Kabu\[Book1.csv]Sheet1'!R[1]C[-4])=0,""0"",('C:\Users\prosp\Documents\Kabu\[Book1.csv]Sheet1'!R[1]C[-1])-('C:\Users\prosp\Documents\Kabu\[Book1.csv]Sheet1'!R[1]C[-4]))"
    Range("F4").Select

End Sub
```

How can I call the .csv file with that code?
Is there anyone who can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import / convert the CSV file into Excel first. Otherwise you cannot access it with a formula. That is because a CSV file is just a text file with comma separated values like shown below:

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

A CSV file has no rows and columns like an Excel file that you can easily access. Therefore it has to be converted into an XLSX first. So it becomes:

```
      A       B         C        D
1 | Year | Make    | Model  | Length |
2 | 1997 | Ford    | E350   |   2.34 |
3 | 2000 | Mercury | Cougar |   2.38 |
```

And now you can access it with a formula by its row and column.

So I suggest to open the CSV file and save it as XLSX first.
Also see [VBA converting csv Files in a folder to xlsx Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757897/vba-converting-csv-files-in-a-folder-to-xlsx-files).