# Excel VBA - Open all .csv files and save as .xlsx using cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to:

1. open all .csv files in the same folder.
2. save a copy each in .xlsx format.
3. with the .xlsx format file name as the Range(“B1”).Value from the corresponding .csv file.

Here is my code so far (not working):

```
Dim MyFolderPath As String
MyFolderPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

myFolderPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
MyFileName = Dir(myFolderPath & "\" & "*.csv")

While MyFileName <> ""
    Set CSVWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(myFolderPath & "\" & MyFileName)
    CSVWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=myFolderPath & "\" & CSVWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Value & ".xlsx"
    CSVWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Wend
```

Could anyone help me to identify the issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757897/vba-converting-csv-files-in-a-folder-to-xlsx-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello TropicalMagic...

try this

```
 `Sub test()
Dim MyFolderPath As String
Dim CSVworkbook As Workbook
Dim MyfileName As Variant
Dim NewFilename As String

MyFolderPath = Application.DefaultFilePath


MyfileName = Dir(MyFolderPath & "\" & "*.csv")

While MyfileName <> ""
    Set CSVworkbook = Workbooks.Open(MyFolderPath & "\" & MyfileName)
    NewFilename = CSVworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Text
    CSVworkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=MyFolderPath & "\" & NewFilename & ".xlsx"
    CSVworkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    MyfileName = Dir
Wend

End Sub`
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! However, I am unable to open the .xlsx files as the error states: "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid"

Answer (score 1):

Another point to mention. Ensure you have data in the Sheets(1)  "b1" range.
If you open an empty CSV in excel and put something in B1,  Save it and reopen and you will see the text in B1 will have moved to A1 due to the way excel interprets CSV's and there being no control or delimiters in an empty CSV Spread sheet. To get around this put something in A1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding! I have found a solution as well:

```
Dim MyFolderPath As String
Dim CSVworkbook As Workbook
Dim MyFileName As Variant
Dim NewFileName As String

MyFolderPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
MyFileName = Dir(MyFolderPath & "\" & "*.csv")

While MyFileName <> ""
    Set CSVworkbook = Workbooks.Open(MyFolderPath & "\" & MyFileName)
    NewFileName = CSVworkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1").Text
    CSVworkbook.SaveAs MyFolderPath & "\" & NewFileName & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    CSVworkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    MyFileName = Dir
Wend
```

Cheers

Comment: Glad you got it going. You don't strictly need the New file bit I added but it helps to fault find. The code I send works ok on my PC so changing that one bit shouldn't make a difference.  If you feel my answer basically got you there could you mark it as an answer please.. Thanks

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help!